# How to filter out multiple values assigned to a specific name in my filer column?

Tags: excel

I need to create an Excel template with f.e following columns and data:

[Example of an Excel Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYuBp.jpg)

and so on. So my goal is to set up the filter in such a way, that when I choose A1 from A column, I can get all the related B,C and D values, like B1,C1,D1; B1.1,C1.1,D1.1;B1.2,C1.2,D1.2
With the normal filter I can only see B1,C1,D1 when I choose A1. 
The only solution I came up with, is writing A1 in every row that has relevant B 1.x ,C 1.x and D 1,x. Then I can see all relevant stuff, but this solution is not the most effective one(especially when values inserted will be a small text, writing same sentences in each row makes it look a bit messy)

The Pivot Table also does not recognize B1.1 C1.1,D1.1; B1.2 C1.2,D1.2 as related to A1. Even when I copied A1 in every row, it still couldn't sort it correctly.

Can you please help me with these quesitons? Many thanks in advance!
Kamola.

**Update**:  I created a following example for clarification, hope it will help a bit! Unfortunately I cannot share the Excel Sheet per Stack Overflow, so here is a screenshot of it:[Example of the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcvTA.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help others better understand your question, could you please share some sample data laying out the relationships between A, B and C, and demonstrate clearly what you want to achieve, and what potential solutions you have looked at but did not solve your case.

Comment: Hi Terry, thank you for your message! I added an example in my post. Unfortunately I am not allowed to share actual table data, so I hope my improvised example helps a bit:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **MANUAL APPROACH**

In your example which is a **Table** but not a pivot table,

1. Highlight Column `Problems` in your table;
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> on your keyboard to bring out the **Go To** window;
3. Click **Special...** button at the left corner of the window;
4. Select **Blanks** then click OK;
5. Do not alter anything, go to the formula bar and enter `=A2`, then hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you have done the above steps correctly, you should have column A filled with Problem IDs.

---

> **POWER QUERY APPROACH**

FYI, if you are using Excel 2010 Professional Plus or later versions of Excel, you can add your data table to Power Query Editor, right click the column header of the first column and select **Fill** -> **Down** to quickly fill the column with all Problem ID.

---

> **PIVOT TABLE APPROACH**

If you want to show row labels in each line in a pivot table (as mentioned in your post), click somewhere within the pivot table, go to `Design` tab in the Excel ribbon, click `Report Layout` and select **Repeat All Item Labels**.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you for your help:) This accelerates the filling out, but my question is: is there a way to make Excel understand that all "Solution A.x"  are assigned to the Problem A and should be displayed when I choose "Problem A" in my filter without filling out the empty rows with additional "Problem A" text? Or is multiple "Problem A" in each row the only possible way?

Comment: @Kamola you need to have a table laying out the relationship between main category and sub categories to start with. Excel is not able to read your mind and pick the subcategories for you without knowing who is the main category. If your source data is missing the main category in the first column as in your example, then you can use my first method to quickly fill out the main category, then you can create a pivot table in which you can filter the main category and the pivot table will be able to show you the corresponding sub categories. Hope it is clear for you.