# How to create a translation table in excel

Tags: excel

I am looking to match up cells that have duplicate data. For example if Column B has a duplicate name, but column A is not populated in one of the duplicates, i want to assign the value in the above duplicate cell to the below cell. I tried using an if statement, but that does not work for what I am looking to do. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. My apology if I did not explain this very clearly.

I have added an image of what I am looking to do: [Translation Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBoBB.png)

Comment: please refer to the answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58407789/how-to-filter-out-multiple-values-assigned-to-a-specific-name-in-my-filer-column/58412728#58412728)

Comment: Thanks Terry. I am trying this in office 365. What I am looking to do is populate the duplicate data ID's with the same ID for thousands of records. I am not sure the method you descibe above works in office 365. Also, would this method gather the above data, and write it to the cell below. So if Column A has a value of 50 and its corresponding Column B is "PAPER PLANES" with the duplicate name "PAPER PLANES" below that in column B and a blank Column A, I am trying to find the correct process or formula to handle thousands of duplicates like that. is there maybe an alternate method in 365?

Comment: In my answer I provided a solution using `#PowerQuery`, simply load the source data to the power query editor, right click the header of Column A, and choose to **Fill** ---> **Down**; besides, the manual solution I provided should also work in your case if you are only looking for a one-off fill down of same value based on its precedent.